# Prism JS not working inside AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prism.js

Prism JS library is not working inside an AngularJS project. I have tried all solutions mentioned here(SO) as well as on other tutorials, but copy pasting the whole code even from CodePen, doesn't give the same outputs. Very strange. Following is the code:

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-markup">
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Output:
[image]

I have downloaded the `prism.js` and `prism.css` files with all options, and these files are included in `app.html` and the above code is in a template named `index.html`. Don't know what's the problem.

Comment: it should work fine. Please create a plnkr to make your problem reproduceable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlights don't work in external template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283191/highlights-dont-work-in-external-template)

Comment: Please Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283191/highlights-dont-work-in-external-template). Templates loaded through with angularjs won't be rendered by prism. You can use this [Prism Directive](https://github.com/sercaneraslan/angular-prism-directive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that instead of `<` and `>`, we need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`, then only it works. That's all.